# Angular Error: [$injector:unpr] while adding ui.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've built simple angular page but after addition of ui.bootstrap to the dependencies I got an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20HomeController
```

Here is reference part of the index.html file:

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/AngularFormsApp.js"></script>
<script src="app/EmployeeForm/efController.js"></script>
<script src="app/EmployeeForm/efDirective.js"></script>
<script src="app/DataService.js"></script>
```

and this is my application js:

```
var angularFormsApp = angular.module('angularFormsApp',['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);
angularFormsApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "app/Home.html",
            controller: "HomeController"
        }).when("/newEmployeeForm", {
            templateUrl: "app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html",
            controller: "efController"
        }).when("/updateEmployeeForm/:id", {
            templateUrl: "app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html",
            controller: "efController"
        }).otherwise({
                redirectTo:"/home"
        });
});

angularFormsApp.controller("HomeController",
function ($scope, $location, $modal,DataService) {
    $scope.showCreateEmployeeForm = function () {
          $location.path('/newEmployeeForm');
        $modal.open(
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html',
            controller: 'efController'
        });
    };
    $scope.showUpdateEmployeeForm = function (id) {
        $location.path('/updateEmployeeForm/'+id);
    };
});
```

Any ideas what did I wrong? Whitout ui.bootstrap reference the page runs well.

Comment: Have you included the source for `$modal`?

Comment: Yes. Here: function ($scope, $location, $modal,DataService) {

Comment: Do you have to include `ui-bootstrap.js` and the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` files or did that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More recent versions changed `$modal` to `$uibModal`.

Same `ui` prefix was added to a number of the services.
See docs examples

Answer (score 1):

To utilize the full power of UIB include the ng-animate script and inject it into your module. This will add animation to your modal.

Comment: not true ... tmpls version includes both. You are misinterpreting the docs